# Unable to run sonarqube web

Tags: sonarqube

wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 14:38:16.567 [WrapperSimpleAppMain] WARN org.sonar.application.config.JdbcSettings - Both 'JDBC_EMBEDDED_PORT' and 'JDBC_URL' properties are set. The value of property 'JDBC_URL' ('jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true') is not consistent with the value of property 'JDBC_EMBEDDED_PORT' ('9092'). The value of property 'JDBC_URL' will be ignored and value 'jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar' will be used instead. To remove this warning, either remove property 'JDBC_URL' if your intent was to use the embedded H2 database, otherwise remove property 'JDBC_EMBEDDED_PORT'.
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:38:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\sonarqube-7.9.1\temp
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:38:17 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:38:17 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\sonarqube-7.9.1\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\sonarqube-7.9.1\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\sonarqube-7.9.1\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\sonarqube-7.9.1\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:38:17 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:38:19 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:38:19 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:39:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:39:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\sonarqube-7.9.1]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\sonarqube-7.9.1\temp --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/common/*;C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\sonarqube-7.9.1\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\sonarqube-7.9.1\temp\sq-process4805941934034955239properties
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:39:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:39:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.08.05 14:39:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped

Comment: What have you done to diagnose this? Have you check SonarQube's other log files (es.log, web.log), tried changing any settings, has this run before etc?

Comment: There is a good chance that the configuration is incorrect. Comment all entries and look if SonarQube can be started.Then review the SonarQube documentation and your configuration.